# Doing (very) small batches of beer

Tags: beer, small-batch

I was wondering if, for the sake of testing, it was a good idea to do very small batches of beer. I almost always see batches of 5, 6 gallons. I would like to make tests, and I don't want them to take 46 bottles of 500ml! :)

I wanted to know what are the possible bad things about brewing small quantities of beer.  And by small I mean down to 1 gallon.

I read once that bigger batches are better.  If this is true, could anyone explain why it is?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Your question is sort of already answered [here](http://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/7346/brew-in-a-bag-one-gallon-batch?rq=1), but I will elaborate on  my experience in the answers.

Comment: I just did my first small batch and the point about the higher evaporation rate is right on. Next time I'll have to adjust a bit.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have been brewing 1-gallon batches at home, and 5-gallon batches at a friend's house, so I have some knowledge on this point. To me, these are the pros and cons with small batches:

**Pros:**

- My spaghetti pot is large enough to do a full boil.
- It takes very little room, all of my equipment stores in a small plastic bin, and I can easily ferment anywhere in my house that is my desired temperature.
- I can do full boils on my kitchen stove.
- Boil times on one-gallon recipe kits are only 45 min.
- I never have to make a starter.
- It will be easy and cheap for me to experiment with all-grain ("mini-mash"), using my spaghetti pot and colander, or my $10 2-gallon beverage cooler with a small paint-strainer bag, for mashing.
- I have the option to do a partial boil 2- or 3-gallon batch, split it between jugs, and experiment with different yeasts, fermenting temperatures, different dry hopping or spices, etc.
- Bottling is quick.
- I can chill in an ice bath in my kitchen sink in 5-10 minutes.
- Cleaning 1-gal. equipment is easy because it is small and light.
- I am not stuck drinking 48-52 bottles of my lesser product.

**Cons:**

- It takes almost the same amount of work and time to make as a 5-gallon batch.
- It is harder to find 1-gallon recipe kits, and the selection less diverse.  Northern Brewer has a good selection of extract kits.  Midwest Supplies has a few all-grain kits (Micro Bru), and Brooklyn Brew Shop has a decent selection.
- Fermenting in 1-gallon jugs, there is little head space, so I lose about a bottle through the blowoff tube.
- The yield is only about eight 12-oz. bottles, so after sharing I will end up with around four bottles.
- There is not enough beer to sample as it ages.
- It seems like evaporation loss during boil is higher.
- The batch is too small to take a hydrometer reading, unless you don't mind either losing 10-12% of your beer per sample or dumping the sample tube contents back into the rest of the beer (use great sanitizing processes!)  So I invested in a refractometer.
- It is not cost-efficient to use liquid yeast, so I am limited to dry yeasts (not that this is a problem for the basic styles that I have brewed or plan to brew in the near future).
- Swings in indoor temperature affect a 1-gal. jug a lot quicker (probably due to lower thermal mass, and greater surface area/volume ratio).
- Mixing small batches of Star-San requires a syringe.
- I am not going to be kegging 1-gallon batches (although some people have been kegging in 1.5L mini-kegs).

Note:  I bought 5-gal. equipment and propane burner this week, and have a larger kettle, and am considering brewing primarily 5-gal. batches due to the yield issue.  The guys on [Basic Brewing Radio/Video](http://www.basicbrewing.com/) do a lot of experimentation using 1-gallon batches, so you may wish to check out their archives. Also check out [this article they wrote in BYO magazine](http://byo.com/european-pale-lager/item/1378-small-scale-brewing).

Comment: Great list of pros and cons! Thanks! Considering I'm doing all-grain, I shouldn't have trouble finding well-sized recipes :)

So there's no such thing as having a lesser quality product with smaller batches?

Comment: I do all-grain 1-gallon batches, and I would not say that my product is of a lesser quality at all.

Comment: I brew 2 gallon batches every once in a while (all-grain BIAB), sometimes as a small test batch or just to scratch the brewing itch. These often end up in a 5L keg, which fits in my fridge. I recommend the book "Beer Craft"; it's an intro-to-homebrewing type book but the recipes and techniques are for 1 gallon batches and small apartment brewing.
http://www.amazon.com/Beer-Craft-Simple-Guide-Making/dp/1605291331/